# How to set a frame title at the top of each page break in a tcolorbox frame

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I am trying to write a LaTeX setting that reproduce the way `a2ps` is displaying source code. Here is an example of such layout:

[image: a2ps layout]

For now, I try to use tcolorbox to build such layout. Here is a simplified attempt I did:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,7pt,landscape,twocolumn]{article}

%% Build with: pdflatex -shell-escape example.tex

%% Font packages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Minted
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}


%% Display the file 'filename' (possibly on several pages) and
%% highlight the syntax for the programming language 'language' as for
%% minted. The filename displayed can optionally be changed.
%%
%% \codeinput[displayed_name]{filename}{language}
%%
\newtcbinputlisting{\codeinput}[3][]{%
  title={\large\bfseries\tt%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax{#2}\else{#1}\fi},
  listing engine=minted,
  minted options={autogobble,breaklines},
  minted language=#3,
  listing file={#2},
  listing only,
  size=title,
  breakable,
  height fill,
  enhanced,
  overlay first={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
  overlay middle={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);%
                  \draw[line width=.75pt](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
  overlay last={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
  colframe=black,
  colbacktitle=lightgray!85,
  coltitle=black,
  boxrule=.75pt,
  colback=white,
  coltext=black
}

\begin{document}
%% Display the source file
\codeinput[libtrie/src/trie.c]{./trie.c}{c}
\end{document}
```

And, I am getting the following result once compiled:

[image: LaTeX source code]

I have two problems:

1. How can we repeat the frame title at the top of each new page break ?
2. A minor cosmetic bug is that the height of the first page of the breakable page is slightly less than the ones afterward. If someone knows where does it comes and how to fix it, it would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer (took me quite a while so I will explain it here to spare time for the others).

So, the right option to consider is `title after break=<Title>`. In fact, it does exactly what is expected. If we take the initial minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{article}

%% Build with: pdflatex -shell-escape example.tex

%% Font packages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Minted
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}


%% Display the file 'filename' (possibly on several pages) and
%% highlight the syntax for the programming language 'language' as for
%% minted. The filename displayed can optionally be changed.
%%
%% \codeinput[displayed_name]{filename}{language}
%%
\newtcbinputlisting{\codeinput}[3][]{%
  title={\large\bfseries\tt%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax{#2}\else{#1}\fi},
  title after break={\large\bfseries\tt%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax{#2}\else{#1}\fi},
  listing engine=minted,
  minted options={autogobble,breaklines},
  minted language=#3,
  listing file={#2},
  listing only,
  size=title,
  breakable,
  height fill,
  enhanced,
  overlay first={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
  overlay middle={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);%
                  \draw[line width=.75pt](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
  overlay last={\draw[line width=.75pt](frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
  colframe=black,
  colbacktitle=lightgray!85,
  coltitle=black,
  boxrule=.75pt,
  colback=white,
  coltext=black
}

\begin{document}
%% Display the source file
\codeinput[libtrie/src/trie.c]{./trie.c}{c}
\end{document}
```

We get, as expected:

[image: full a2ps clone]

Note also that the small shift between the first and the second page has also disappeared.